# How do i render a form ModelChoicefield's attributes in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created my form like so,

```
class PartialOrderItemform(forms.Form):
        option = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = OptionalItems.objects.all(),widget= forms.RadioSelect())

        def __init__(self,item ,*args, **kwargs):
            super(PartialOrderItemform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['option'].queryset = OptionalItem.objects.filter(item=item)
```

views.py

```
def show_item(request,id):
    ....
    final_form = form.PartialOrderItemform(item=id)
    ....
```

All the above is working just fine, my problem is rendering in the templates, doing some thing like this `{% for option in form.option %} {{option}}` works fine, why is this not working `{{ option.price }}`.

Clearly there is something i am not understanding thus my asking here, why can't i access the option's attributes and what is the right way to go about it.

Comment: does `option.queryset.price` work?

Comment: @alecxe it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately ModelChoiceField's iterator only returns tuple (value, label), so you need to make some overriding to make it work, this link should help you out:

https://github.com/simensen/srcmvn.com/blob/master/source/_posts/2013-01-15-django-advanced-model-choice-field.md

Answer (score 0):

You're not really supposed to iterate over form fields like that. Just do:

```
{{ form.option }}
```

Comment: i know that works but what if i want to be able to render the options attribute, thats what i want learn how to achieve and have pointed it out in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a model_formset? Not sure why you're using a regular form and initialising the queryset twice, when you want to make a formset based on a filtered Model queryset. Something like this:

```
class PartialOrderItemformSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PartialOrderItemformSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = OptionalItem.objects.filter(item=item)
```

Now in your template you should be able to access the underlying Models unary methods inside your for loop with:

```
{{form.instance.price}}
```